# Labels not working for volcano plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, bioinformatics, matlab-guide

I am a complete newbie to MATLAB and the first task I have is to create a volcano plot. I have been using [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/mavolcanoplot.html) to understand about it and get started.

I am using the following dummy data to get started -

```
Fer1l6  0   0.116815    3.39E-07
Selenoo 0.231255    2.104358    3.17E-06
Myh9    0   0   3.52E-05
SCARNA8 0   0   5.90E-05
7SK 0.4105501   1.593424    7.53E-05
Cnksr1  0.2652796   0.276202    0.000142596
Kcng3   0   0.947934    0.0003170
Acaa1b  0.97177 2.25452 0.0003906
adsf    0.44    0.35    0.3
```

Here, the *first column* stands for the gene_name, *second column* for gene expression values for condition 1, *third column* for gene expression values for condition 2, and the *last column* for the P-value. I have this data in an Excel file.

Now, to create the volcano plot, I wrote the following code -

```
filename='quant_data_for_volcano.xlsx';

youngdata=xlsread(filename,'B:B')
olddata=xlsread(filename,'A:A')
pvalues=xlsread(filename,'C:C')
gene_labels=xlsread(filename,'D:D')
SigStructure = mavolcanoplot(youngdata, olddata, pvalues, 'LogTrans', true, 'Labels', gene_labels)
```

My understanding is that the 'Labels' argument takes the labels for the various genes (gene_names in this case). However, when I run this code, it does not give me the gene_name labels in the GUI, rather it just gives me the row number as the gene labels - **which is what it is supposed to do when I don't provide any labels!**

I have attached the output GUI as a picture - as you can see the labels for the genes are just numbers (which correspond to the row number).

The manual says that the labels should be a Cell Array, 'i am not sure if that is important, and if it is, then how to implement it. Any help would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as you've figured out, `mavolcanoplot()` requires a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html), you'll want `xlsread()` to return a cell array instead of a matrix:

```
[num, gene_labels]=xlsread(filename,'D:D') % (num is a matrix while gene_labels is a cell array)
```

Comment: and then, just call `gene_labels` as before. Thanks, that worked!

Comment: ok, so if we declare a matrix as `[a,b]`, then `a` gets assigned as the whole matrix and `b` as the first array of cells?

Comment: They both get assigned the whole matrix, it's just that `a` will get any numerical data as a regular MATLAB array, while `b` will get any text data as a cell array. In your particular example, `num` will be empty since there aren't any numerical values in column D.

Comment: ok, so the first variable gets the numerical data and the second gets the text data. And ALSO, the first variable becomes a regular MATLAB array and the second becomes the cell array. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly, and they only get the data that is specified by the second argument of `xlsread()` of course.

Comment: I was actually hoping to be wrong there, since it is difficult for me to understand that assigning like `[a,b]` would accomplish BOTH the tasks I mentioned i.e. 1) the first variable gets the numerical data and the second gets the text data; and 2)  the first variable becomes a regular MATLAB array and the second becomes the cell array. Is that actually true?

Comment: That's what the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#btg5vmt-4) states.